# Concatenate two rows with the same ID into 0,1,2 from presence/absence

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to record an original table with `SNP ID` in rows and Sample `ID` in columns.

So far, I only managed to convert the data into presence/absence with 0 and 1.

I tried some easy codes to do further conversion but cannot find one that does I want.

The original table looks like this

```
snpID   Cal_X1  Cal_X2  Cal_X3  Cal_X4  Cal_X5  Cal_X6  Cal_X7  Cal_X8
A_001   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
A_001   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
A_002   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
A_002   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1
A_003   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0
A_003   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
A_004   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
A_004   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0
```

I would like to record the scores to 0/0 = NA, 0/1 = 0, 1/1 = 2, 1/0 = 1 so the product looks something like this.

```
snpID   Cal_X1  Cal_X2  Cal_X3  Cal_X4  Cal_X5  Cal_X6  Cal_X7  Cal_X8
A_001   NA         1       2       1       0       NA      2      0
A_002   1          2       0       1       2       1       0      0
A_003   2          0       NA      2       0       1       1      0
A_004   0          NA      1       0       NA      2       0      NA
```

This is just an example. My total `snpID` is ~96000 and total sample `ID` column is ~500.

Any helps with writing this code would be really appreciated.

Comment: Note that you have a few typos in your expected output.

Comment: Fixed it. Good spot. Thanks Markus!

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the answers if they made you happy. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few `dplyr`-based examples that each work in a single pipe and get the same output. The main first step is to group by your ID, then collapse all the columns with a `/`. Then you can use `mutate_at` to select all columns that start with `Cal_`—this may be useful if you have other columns besides the ID that you *don't* want to do this operation on.

First method is a `case_when`:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(snpID) %>%
  summarise_all(paste, collapse = "/") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Cal_")), ~case_when(
    . == "0/1" ~ 0,
    . == "1/1" ~ 2,
    . == "1/0" ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 9
#>   snpID Cal_X1 Cal_X2 Cal_X3 Cal_X4 Cal_X5 Cal_X6 Cal_X7 Cal_X8
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 A_001     NA      1      2      1      0     NA      2      0
#> 2 A_002      1      2      0      1      2      1      0      0
#> 3 A_003      2      0     NA      2      0      1      1      0
#> 4 A_004      0     NA      1      0     NA      2      0     NA
```

However, (in my opinion) `case_when` is a little tricky to read, and this doesn't showcase its real power, which is doing if/else checks on *multiple* variables. Better suited to checks on one variable at a time is `dplyr::recode`:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(snpID) %>%
  summarise_all(paste, collapse = "/") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Cal_")), 
            ~recode(., 
                    "0/1" = 0,
                    "1/1" = 2,
                    "1/0" = 1,
                    "0/0" = NA_real_))
# same output as above
```

Or, for more flexibility & readability, create a small lookup object. That way, you can reuse the recode logic and change it easily. `recode` takes a set of named arguments; using tidyeval, you can pass in a named vector and unquo it with `!!!` (there's a similar example in the `recode` docs):

```r
lookup <- c("0/1" = 0, "1/1" = 2, "1/0" = 1, "0/0" = NA_real_)

dat %>%
  group_by(snpID) %>%
  summarise_all(paste, collapse = "/") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Cal_")), recode, !!!lookup)
# same output
```

Comment: Not sure if I agree that your last option is more readable than `case_when` (the `!!!` makes it hard(er) to apply/remember IMHO) but definitely a good answer. I try to use `baseR` as much as I can and thought that `case_when` would increase readability compared to multiple nested `ifelse`, no?

Comment: @markus anything is better than 4 nested `ifelse`s! For me, something like `recode` or `fct_recode` makes more sense when all the values come from one place. And if there's something that functions like a lookup table, I like having it in a separate variable—once I get into a bigger project, I want to see where exactly something like that is declared and have access to it to reuse. But that's totally a matter of preference & context. I probably have more `case_when` situations on a day to day basis

Comment: I actually need to ask one more question. I used the second code and I get this warning "Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default". The data look fine to me but I cannot eyeball all of them. I searched for solutions and tried changing " to ' and added dplyr:: in front of recode but still get the same warning. Any help?

Comment: I think that means that there are values in your data that aren't covered by the lookup. It also may be that you're replacing with `NA`—`NA` values are actually typed, which is why I used `NA_real_` to make sure it was interpreted as numeric

Comment: Yes, I have NAs in dat before the recode. Thank you Camille!

Answer (score 0):

You might use `aggregate` to concatenate the values for each `snpID` and then replace the values according to your needs with the help of `case_when` from `dplyr`.

```
(out <- aggregate(.~ snpID, dat, toString))
#  snpID Cal_X1 Cal_X2 Cal_X3 Cal_X4 Cal_X5 Cal_X6 Cal_X7 Cal_X8
#1 A_001   0, 0   1, 0   1, 1   1, 0   0, 1   0, 0   1, 1   0, 1
#2 A_002   1, 0   1, 1   0, 1   1, 0   1, 1   1, 0   0, 1   0, 1
#3 A_003   1, 1   0, 1   0, 0   1, 1   0, 1   1, 0   1, 0   0, 1
#4 A_004   0, 1   0, 0   1, 0   0, 1   0, 0   1, 1   0, 1   0, 0
```

Now recode the columns

```
library(dplyr)
out[-1] <- case_when(out[-1] == "0, 0" ~ NA_integer_,
                     out[-1] == "0, 1" ~ 0L,
                     out[-1] == "1, 0" ~ 1L,
                     TRUE ~ 2L)
```

Result

```
out
#  snpID Cal_X1 Cal_X2 Cal_X3 Cal_X4 Cal_X5 Cal_X6 Cal_X7 Cal_X8
#1 A_001     NA      1      2      1      0     NA      2      0
#2 A_002      1      2      0      1      2      1      0      0
#3 A_003      2      0     NA      2      0      1      1      0
#4 A_004      0     NA      1      0     NA      2      0     NA
```

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(snpID = c("A_001", "A_001", "A_002", "A_002", 
"A_003", "A_003", "A_004", "A_004"), Cal_X1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Cal_X2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    Cal_X3 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Cal_X4 = c(1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Cal_X5 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L), Cal_X6 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    Cal_X7 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Cal_X8 = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("snpID", "Cal_X1", 
"Cal_X2", "Cal_X3", "Cal_X4", "Cal_X5", "Cal_X6", "Cal_X7", "Cal_X8"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the -1 index?

Comment: @camille It's because of the `snpID` column. Would probably work without I suppose..will test. Ah, without it we'd another case a la `out == "1, 1" ~ 2L`  and `TRUE ~ out$snpID` so we might save a few characters.